# PHP doesn't handle stack overflow?

Tags: php, crash, segmentation-fault, stack-overflow

I was surprised when I just tried the following PHP code:

```
function foo()
{
    foo();
}
foo();
```

I expected to get "500: Internal server error". Instead the connection was closed immediately (no bytes received), and the log files show that apache segfaulted. WTF? Is this a known bug in PHP? Are there some configuration options that I'm missing? Because a crashed process for every accidental stack overflow is, well... pretty unacceptable, I think.

Comment: Probably the compiler saw what you did there and thought *oh boy, clever-time... leave me the hell alone...*

Comment: No doubt. Especially because PHP doesn't have a compiler. :p

Comment: I don't think that the crash is an optimization. On the other hand, how should PHP handle something like that more gracefully?

Comment: You shouldn't expect PHP to give nice error messages when it sees something like this: http://lorienshaw.net/hasselhoff.html

Comment: Another reason not to use PHP

Comment: Ah well PHP is good for some parts of WebDev... And okay, it's an interpreter, whatever...

Comment: As I said - it should handle it like any other unhandled runtime error (such as an uncaught exception). It should give some error message (can you say "stack overflow"?) and return a 500 HTTP status code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP is not able to deal with this, it will just go into an infinite loop and produce a segmentation fault.

http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49823

also

http://www.mail-archive.com/php-bugs@lists.php.net/msg128905.html

Comment: Sweet. Can't wait until production upgrades to PHP 5.3 then. :P

Answer (score 2):

avoid using recursive functions they are generally a bad idea" 0 riiight:))) they were invented because its a bad ideea:))...

I recomment setting a hrd upper-limit on the number of times the functions is called. DO NOT use global variables (you may actually need to call more recursive functions, why pollute the globals like this?). You may use extra parameters for a function

```
function a($param1, $param2, $depth=100){
  $depth--;
  if(!$depth==0) return error
}
```

Comment: That's not the point. Sure I can code with many safeguards of my own. But bugs are inevitable, and sooner or later there will be a StackOverflow as well. Most likely the recursion won't be intended, like one function calling another which in turn calls the first one. Having a nondescript segfault in this case doesn't help at all.

Comment: True, dont know what happens if a debug version of the php module is used. By default, any app that overflows will generate a segfault and quit... because its a segfault. Special (slow) debug code must be added to a file to handle stack overflows, thats probably why the php interpreter dosen't handle it.

You may also try using xdebug and/or suhosin

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [iBlog - Ilia Alshanetsky](http://ilia.ws/archives/5_Top_10_ways_to_crash_PHP.html)

> Stack overflow. PHP does not have any
>   internal stack protection choosing to
>   rely upon the system stack without any
>   protection. This means that if you
>   have a recursive function or a method
>   PHP will eventually crash.
>
> ```
> function a() { a(); } a();
> ```
>
> There are 2 solutions to this problem,
>   1 avoid using recursive functions they
>   are generally a bad idea anyway, and
>   if you MUST use them implement some
>   counter using a global variable that
>   would prevent the function from
>   iterating itself more then X amount of
>   time for values of X between 500 to
>   1000. The other solution involves using the xdebug extension that
>   implements protection against stack
>   overflows by defining a limit on how
>   deep can recursive functions go via a
>   php.ini value. This is a better
>   solution in hosting environments where
>   you have no control over the scripts
>   that are being ran on the server.

Comment: Good info about xdebug, but I'd contest your statement that recursive functions are a bad idea. Yes, they can be tricky to use, but for some situations (like tree traversal) they are the most efficient way to go.

Comment: Actually its totally taken from somewhere else, and I thought about commenting on bad recursive functions. Dont get me wrong I know the power of recursion, I just didnt want to modify the quote.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a known bug. See the list [Top 10 ways to crash PHP](http://ilia.ws/archives/5-Top-10-ways-to-crash-PHP.html).

Comment: Interesting quote from the linked article: "avoid using recursive functions they are generally a bad idea anyway".