# Why this DOM-replaceNode function sometimes crashes?

Tags: php, domdocument

The first function (below) works fine, in a loop over many nodes of the same [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)... **But sometimes crashes** (no error message but stopping the server).

When we use the second (`replace_innerXML_secure`), in the same node loop, it never crashes. Why? **What is wrong with the first?**

- The first use `$e->nodeValue=''` to delete all *childNodes* (**it its ok?**);
- The second preserves one (arbitrary) *childNode* and use [removeChild](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php) to delete... A extrange workaround to avoid full deletion when some tag was there.

---

The "equivalent" functions #1 and #2:

```
// 1. What is wrong with THIS function??
function replace_innerXML(DOMNode $e,$innerXML='') {
    if ($e && ($innerXML>'' || $e->nodeValue>'')) {
        $e->nodeValue='';   
        if ($innerXML>'') {
            $tmp = $this->dom->createDocumentFragment();
            $tmp->appendXML($innerXML);
            $e->appendChild( $tmp );
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// 2. Here a workaround... slower but... NOT crashes (!), WHY??
function replace_innerXML_secure(DOMNode $e,$innerXML='') {
    if ($e) {
        $tmp = $e->ownerDocument->createDocumentFragment();
        $tmp->appendXML($innerXML);
        $once=null;         
        foreach(iterator_to_array($e->childNodes) as $e2)
            if (!$once && $e2->nodeType===1) $once=$e2;
            else $e->removeChild($e2);
        if ($once)
            $once->parentNode->replaceChild( $tmp, $once );
        else {
            $e->nodeValue='';
            $e->appendChild( $tmp );
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

## NOTES

**EDIT2** for @Prix request, some example.

The loop is very complex,  but it can be simulated as

```
   // use this with ANY (and a lot of) BIG HTML files from web... 
   // I have ~1 error/100 samples  
   $dom = new DOMDocument();
   $dom->load($file); // any XML, or loadHTMLfile() 

   $plst = array();  // you can take off the rand()
   foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('*') as $node) if (1 || rand(1,3)==1) {
      $plst[] = $node->getNodePath();
   }
   rsort($plst); // from leaves to root
   foreach ($plst as $p) {
      $xp = new DOMXpath($dom); // refresh for each $p
      $node = $xp->query($p);
      if ($node->length && $node=$node->item(0))
          // USING HERE the function#1 or #2:
          replace_innerXML($node,'<new x="1">text</new>');
   }
   $dom->normalizeDocument();
```

Here some sample XML for $dom, but you can use any `$dom->loadHTML($file)` to test (!).

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  
  <article dtd-version="3.0" article-type="research-article" xml:lang="en">
    <front><journal-meta>
        <journal-title-group><journal-title>text text text</journal-title>
        <abbrev-journal-title abbrev-type="acronym">aaaa</abbrev-journal-title>
        <abbrev-journal-title abbrev-type="publisher">aaabbb aaa</abbrev-journal-title>
        </journal-title-group>
        <etc>....</etc>
        <history><date date-type="received"><label>Received</label> 9 July 2014</date>
            <date date-type="accepted"><label>Accepted</label> 25 July 2014</date>
        </history>
    </journal-meta></front>
    <body>
        <p>Nonnnononn onononono  nonono</p>
        <fn><p><label>XXXXX yyyyy</label>: xxxx@aaa.com</p></fn>
  
        <p>Nonnnononn onononono  nonono nonono </p>
    </body>
  </article>
```

**EDIT1** for versions and logs

**Versions:**

- *libxml2:* 2.8.0+dfsg1-7+wheezy1
- *php5*: 5.4.4-14+deb7u14
- *apache2*: 2.2.22-13+deb7u3

**Logs:** where?  I know only `/var/log/apache2/error.log`, but no error there (only a usual png "File does not exist" that are in a sucess http).

... in this machine, running again today, after http crashes, no big error reported, only "File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico" before the crash...  But I was **running also in a Ubuntu machine**, where I find (!) a report about the date and instant of a crash:

```
 [Wed Oct 15 20:16:16.840578 2014] [core:notice] [pid 1770] AH00051: child pid 14873 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
 [Wed Oct 15 20:16:16.840684 2014] [core:notice] [pid 1770] AH00051: child pid 14879 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
 *** Error in `/usr/sbin/apache2': corrupted double-linked list: 0x00007f457b81af70 ***
 [Wed Oct 15 20:16:56.886473 2014] [core:notice] [pid 1770] AH00051: child pid 14844 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
 [Wed Oct 15 20:16:57.887638 2014] [core:notice] [pid 1770] AH00051: child pid 14894 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
```

yes, a big crash, **no clue about why**.  (I remember that the "standard coredump problem" in *LibXML2* is delete or write nodes that not exists).

Comment: Why are you using the greater than operator to compare the variable  with an empty string?

Comment: Hum... yes, in PHP `$a!=''` and `$a>''` are same.  PS: someone downvoted, was the explanation? I edited, better now?

Comment: Oh ok, didn't know that. I wasn't the one who downvoted though.

Comment: I bet there are no messages in Apache logs?

Comment: @rr- I edited... no good log...

Comment: @PeterKrauss Would help if you post an example of the XML you're using that fails with perhaps a sample demo usage code with it actually failing.

Comment: I suspect that direct responsibility for the crash goes to whatever code is using the methods. My guess is that it uses supplied method in a way that leads to an infinite recursion, which in turn is known to cause `SEGFAULT`s.

Comment: @PeterKrauss [where is the sample XML to test?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Prix, ops, sorry, I will send... But you can use any `$dom->loadHTML($file)` to test.

Comment: @PeterKrauss except for `Opening and ending tag mismatch` errors, the script runs just fine here. (Edit: the loaded XML appears to be empty. I'm going to try fixing it manually.)

Comment: Yep, after correcting closing tags for `</front>` and `</journal-meta>`, it still works fine, doing all the replacements like intended. (I've tried running it multiple times, too.)

Comment: @Prix, yes, the function#1 "works fine" as I say... There are only ~1% of cases that make error. I'm sure that is a problem as I descrebed, not need to reproduce, the coredump exists (!)... and it is an "error" on my logic of delete/rewrite nodes in the a big tree... Other good answer to my question is an alternative to function #2, less slower.

Comment: Need of 100 or more BIG samples: perhaps, if you need to reproduce, can get a lot of HTML files from Web or your machine, to a loop over samples ... Use `loadHTMLfile()` or `$h=file_get_contents($url); @$dom->loadHTML($h)` in the loop.

Comment: I have a feeling that your issue is coming from malformed HTML rather than anything else, while DOMDocument does have the ability to fix some HTML it doesn't have the ability to fix any sort of specific case presented to it.

Comment: @Prix, ... unfortunately I'm sure that is not the case: I use only pre-validated XML, and when run another "filter" it works fine. My experience with DOM show that DOM is problematic in write/delete tasks..

Comment: unhappily you haven't provided anything solid that reproduces your issue and no one else who actually tested it was able to get to the same issue you've had or so it seems. I would start by printing each step of what your code is doing, either to a file or screen so you can follow it and see where it exactly fails and what the string is so you can try to pinpoint the issue whether with your code or the file given to it.

Comment: @Prix, ok I undertand your point... I must to do my homework... this weekend I will to prepare it.

Answer (score -1):

While I didn't find anything odd about the code (tested it on my machine with a few XMLs and found no problems), I suspect that something uses it in a way, that leads to an infinite recursion.

Functions that enter too deep recursion are known for causing PHP to `SEGFAULT`s. [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782861/php-doesnt-handle-stack-overflow), [2](http://phpsadness.com/sad/50)]
Either that, or a serious PHP/libxml2 bug.

Perhaps the problem lies elsewhere?

Comment: see notes/edit2: no infinite recursion in PHP code (perhaps libxml2 lost some pointer and do a loop...?).

Comment: Alright, what part about my answer needed downvoting?